# One server, multiple subdomains pointing to different ports

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, subdomain

I have a VPN network at home, which I'm using for multiple things.

I'm running the OpenVPN Server on there, alongside multiple http servers, like Jenkins, WebLogic, etc., and a DNS server, which resolves `ropi.io` to the VPN server.

Knowing what port let's say Jenkins runs on (8081), I can reach it by going to `ropi.io:8081`, which is call and all, but I'd like to reach that server at `jenkins.ropi.io` instead. Now, I know that it cannot be solved with pure DNS and whatever I read about reverse proxies, it seems like the solution is not really in that direction.

The best way I'd think it could be solved is to register a separate IP address for all the servers I'm running and creating a DNS entry for each of them. It sounds like a good solution, but I don't know how I could go about doing it.

Is there any sense to my idea? What can I do to make it a reality? If it makes no sense, then where should I look for the solution?

UI.: The servers I'm trying to create subdomains for are running on separate Docker containers. I thought this might be a helpful info.

Comment: Attach your services to subdomains on port 80 / 443 using Nginx or similar rather than using odd ports on the main domain and forwarding. You don't need separate IPs.

Comment: That is what a reverse proxy does. And yes that is what you need. Or multiple static IPs like you suggested.

Comment: I checked earlier today, and I saw on the nginx site that it's not free (whatever I remembered), so I ruled that option out. I did find a docker image of nginx tho. Am I doing something illegal here?

Comment: Eh? nginx is free and open source. But "nginx plus" is a commercial offering.

Comment: Then I wasn't out of my mind. I got confused, because on the nginx site I haven't found anything about the open-source nginx, only nginx plus. I did start up the nginx docker container, I figured this could be the best way to go about it, because I have DNS resolution for the different containers

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one IP address if port 80 is available:

1. Add wildcard DNS to point to your server's IP.
2. Put a [URL redirector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) on port 80.
3. For each app you are hosting add in a redirect for `foo.ropi.io` to `ropi.io:8000`

Now you can type a URL that you can remember in your browser and you will still end up where you want to go.

Comment: I chose Nginx for this purpose, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this.

I set up my DNS server to resolve the same IP on all of the subdomains I want. Then I used Nginx in docker, to then based on the URL address typed in the browser, redirect the requests to the right ports.

Docker based Nginx is a great solution, because connecting it to a network of my other containers, I now have IP resolution for these containers based on their name, which made it really convenient. Also, this solution would allow me to use unison ports, like 8080, or even 80 for that matter on all of my docker containers, but these port numbers were already a given, so I didn't mess with them, because whatever, my subdomains will mask the port number anyway.

Thank you for reinforcing me in my direction, I really appreciate the help